Big Query Data Transfer - Google Ads multiplied by 1,000,000 issue
We have configured BigQuery Data transfer from Google Ads. Some of the metrics in Big Query tables are multiplied by 1,000,000 and stored in bigqquey table. metrics such as metrics_average_cost, metrics_average_cpc, metrics_average_cpm in ads_AdStats_* table.
Please let me know is it a bug in Big query datatransfer?
metrics_average_cpc should be .53 but Big query table has 530000
metrics_average_cpm should be 530 but Big query table has 530000000

The metrics in BigQuery being multiplied by 1,000,000 is not a bug in the BigQuery Data Transfer Service itself, but rather a result of how Google Ads API represents these values. This is done to avoid precision errors that could arise with floating-point arithmetic in financial calculations and these metrics are directly transferred as they are provided by the Google Ads API. Therefore, the values you see in BigQuery are in micros (i.e., multiplied by 1,000,000).
Eg. If metrics_average_cpc in Google Ads API is 0.53, it is represented as 530000 micros in BigQuery.
SELECT
  metrics_average_cpc / 1000000 AS actual_average_cpc,
  metrics_average_cpm / 1000000 AS actual_average_cpm
FROM
  `egdataset.ads_AdStats_*`

